# How to merge certain commit into another branch

Tags: git

this is my situation

```
master commit1 commit2 develop commit3 commit4 fix
```

I want to create new branch derived from master and add there commit3 and commit4.

I tried:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b master1
git rebase --onto master develop master1
```

but with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b master1 master
git cherry-pick commit3 commit4
```

or if you want to just move the `fix` branch to `master` as base instead of copying `commit3` and `commit4` to your new branch:

```
git rebase --onto master develop fix
```

which reads in human readable form: "move the branch `fix` with all commits newer than develop onto the new parent `master`"

Comment: Thank you for adding the human readable form `git rebase --onto master develop fix` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the last known good revision of master (for example 6 commits ago):

```
git reset HEAD~6
```

Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newmaster
```

Tack on the good commits:

```
git cherry-pick commit3
git cherry-pick commit4
```

Comment: there is no faster way ? What if I have there over 20 commit and  I want to take them all and when there is conflict take I want to take changes from commit3,4 ....

Comment: There may be plenty faster ways. I was just responding to your specific quesion. ;)